# Cloud Run php8-fpm nginx log warning

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy Laravel 9 with PHP-8.2.3-fpm + Nginx on Cloud Run. I'm a bit confused about the right way to configure my Dockerfile but actually it's work but I have some errors in the Cloud Run logs.

[image]

And at the end there is a permission denied on nginx.pid.

Here is my Dockerfile + my Nginx.conf

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2.3-fpm as base

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

WORKDIR /app

# Install Nginx and PHP dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        nginx \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        locales \
    && sed -i -e 's/# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# Env
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8 
ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:en

# Copy project, nginx.conf, config php and install composer
COPY . .
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/custom.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/custom.ini
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Add permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app/vendor \
    mkdir -p /app/storage/logs \
    && useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user \
    && mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer \
    && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user \
    && chown -R $user:$user /app \
    && chmod +x docker/startup-dev.sh \
    && chmod +x docker/startup-prod.sh \
    && chown -R $user:$user /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx /var/www \
    && touch /run/nginx.pid && chown -R $user:$user /run/nginx.pid

EXPOSE 8080

FROM base as development
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/startup-dev.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
USER $user

FROM base as production
COPY docker/opcache.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/opcache.ini
RUN composer clearcache && composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/startup-prod.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
USER $user
```

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;
        root /app/public;
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off; 
            fastcgi_buffering off; 
        }
    }
}
```

The errors only occur in Cloud Run; my local environment is working fine. How can I remove theses errors or maybe there errors are normal in Cloud Run ?

I also have a question about my Dockerfile: is it necessary to use a non-root user (USER $user) for the Cloud Run environment? Would it be okay if I remove USER $user to give the container full root access and avoid permission denied errors? I am considering this because Cloud Run is a Google environment and serverless, perhaps creating a user is unnecessary on Cloud Run, and using root access would be simpler, allowing me to remove the `chown` and `chmod` commands